# Load Testing with 1000 concurrent/virtual users

Tags: testing, load

I need a help, I am planning to perform load testing over a product and i am searching for a tool which can provided me the exact details and also can show me the whole statistics in relevance and also the timestamp.

I was searching for such tool. If anyone knows or comes across something like this than please let me know.

Thanks in advance to all who intend to help.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what this question is about. Are you load testing a router? A web server? A database?

Comment: i m vry sory , i want to test an application which i have created for a callcenter where multiple agents would log in at a same tym, so i wanna check its stability....for tht we need to do load testing and here i m searching for a tool which can match my need

Answer (score 0):

Pre-scriptum: I'm assuming you want to test a web app. Please, provide further details in the question.

Maybe it's too basic but, have you tried using [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)?

Comment: i want to test an application which i have created for a callcenter where multiple agents would log in at a same tym, so i wanna check its stability....for tht we need to do load testing and here i m searching for a tool which can match my need

Answer (score 0):

The two I would start looking at as Jmeter and the Grinder. I would start with Jmeter and if this does not meet your requirements move on to the Grinder.